# Best Magento Shipping Module

Tags: shipping, module, fedex, ups, third-party-module

I was wondering if anyone out there could lead me to a good Magento shipping module that would allow the shop owner to use FedEx, UPS, and/or USPS, and more specifically use there FedEx account number so that they can charge their own shipping rates negotiated by FedEx.

Comment: Checkout http://www.webshopapps.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can highly recommend WebShopApps [click here](http://www.webshopapps.com/eu/)
They have different modules for different needs but always something which suits you. i think it is used in a wide range of magento users.

Especially the dimensional shipping is great because it is compatible with FedEx, UPS and USPS live rates, including international.[Click here to directly there Dimensional Shipping Extension](http://www.webshopapps.com/dimensional-shipping.html)

Comment: This customer is currently on version 1.4.  I am trying to upgrade them to the latest version.  Isn't there FedEx, UPS, and USPS support in the latest version?

Comment: It is supported there.

Comment: Did this help you now?